# determine if a list contains other lists

Tags: python

if I have a list, is there any way to check if it contains any other lists?

what i mean to say is, I want to know if a list has this strcuture: `[]` as opposed to this structure `[[]]`

so, compare [1,2,3,4] to [1,[2,3],4]

this is complicated by the fact that i have a list of strings.

well, phihag's solution seems to be working so far, but what I'm doing is this:

```
uniqueCrossTabs = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(uniqueCrossTabs))
```

in order to flatten a list if it has other lists in it.
But since my list contains strings, if this is done on an already flattened list, I get a list of each character of each string that was in the original list.
This is not the behavior i was looking for. so, checking to see if the list needs to be flattened before flattening is neccessary.

Comment: `if a has contains other lists` and `compare ... to` are mutually exclusive. I suggest you ask another question about comparing flattened lists or sublists. If you're not sure about the wording, please give like 5 examples of comparisons with different results.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

```
any(isinstance(el, list) for el in input_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can take phihag's answer even further if you actually want a **list** of all the lists inside the list:

```
output_list = filter( lambda x: isinstance(x,list), input_list)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
lst1 in lst2
```

Yields True iff lst1 is in lst2.

Comment: Note that containment checking in a list uses equality, not identity.