# Python flatten list (but not all the way)

Tags: python, list, flatten

I have a list of lists of lists...

```
A = [ [[1,3]], [[3,5], [4,4], [[5,3]]] ]
```

the following function outputs `[1, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3]`

```
def flatten(a):
    b = []
    for c in a:
        if isinstance(c, list):
            b.extend(flatten(c))
        else:
            b.append(c)
    return b
```

However, I want to stop flattening on the last level so that I get `[ [1,3], [3,5], [4,4], [5,3] ]`

Comment: This would require a scan of the list to see if there are no lists contained.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yea, I get the above, but the problem is that last element is a list within a list.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: see my answer; just test for lists before flattening.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did that with list comprehension. But yours is generic :)

Comment: You can use this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5251706/1982962) that's the missing part, to check if your list has lists inside it before making the recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could test for contained lists before flattening:

```
def flatten(a):
    b = []
    for c in a:
        if isinstance(c, list) and any(isinstance(i, list) for i in c):
            b.extend(flatten(c))
        else:
            b.append(c)
    return b
```

Demo:

```
>>> def flatten(a):
...     b = []
...     for c in a:
...         if isinstance(c, list) and any(isinstance(i, list) for i in c):
...             b.extend(flatten(c))
...         else:
...             b.append(c)
...     return b
... 
>>> A = [ [[1,3]], [[3,5], [4,4], [[5,3]]] ]
>>> flatten(A)
[[1, 3], [3, 5], [4, 4], [5, 3]]
```

This tries to be as efficient as can be under the circumstances; `any()` only needs to test until a list is found, not all elements.

Comment: Beautifully done, in the end I did the same thing, but I used `chain.from_iterable`.

Answer (score 2):

```
A = [ [[1,3]], [[3,5], [4,4], [[5,3]]] ]

print [child[0] if isinstance(child[0], list) else child for item in A for child in item]
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 3], [3, 5], [4, 4], [5, 3]]
```

**Note:** This solution is strictly for this problem only. This is not a generic list flattening solution.

The same idea, with `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain
print [item[0] if isinstance(child[0], list) else item for item in chain(*A)]
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 3], [3, 5], [4, 4], [5, 3]]
```

Comment: Use `isinstance()` to test for types; `type(...) == typeobj` is very restrictive. Even if `isinstance()` was not available, you should use `is typeobj` anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why is it restrictive? Could you please xplain?

Comment: `isinstance(ob, list)` is `True` for subclasses too, `type(ob) is list` only allows for list objects, not subclasses.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh. Thanks. Updated :) Not a single day passes by without learning something from you. Thanks a lot :)