# "raise" inner list to level of outer list in R

Tags: r, list, flatten

I have a list structure like

```
l = list(c("a","b"),list("a","b"),3)
l

# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "b"
#
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "a"
#
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] "b"
#
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
```

And I want to flatten this to

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "b"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "a"
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "b"
#
#
# [[4]]
# [1] 3
```

and I'm not sure how to proceed. As far as I'm aware this is beyond what `unlist` can handle. I found the answer in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19617334/2954547) that I can follow, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it in R than copying to a new list.